# Kotlin: private mutable property with only getter

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm very new to Kotlin and trying to migrate one project from Java to it. I'm a bit confused with Kotlin's properties and getters/setters for them along with visibility scope.

What I want to achieve is:

```
public class Foo {

    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void increment() {
        number++;
    }

}
```

So basically I need to create a class with a private property `number`. This property should be accessible by the public getter, but it shouldn't have a setter. Also, this property should be internally mutable, so that its value can be changed using some method like `increment()`.

As far as I understand, I can't declare it as `val`, because in that case, it would be completely immutable, even from within the instance of a class, so I can't increment it. Looks like it should be `var`. But then I don't see an option to make the property itself be `private` and the getter for this property to be `public`, because it seems that properties and their getters/setters should have the same visibility scope...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Intellij you could just paste your code into a Kotlin class and would have received the following:

```
class Foo {

  var number: Int = 0
    private set

  fun increment() {
    number++
  }
}
```

And this basically is also the answer to your problem...

`private set` tells that the setter is only privately visible. So you can access it within `Foo`, but not from outside. The `0` you set explicitly (in contrast to Java). Then: by default the property and functions are `public`.

Check also the [Kotlin reference regarding properties (specifically getter/setter)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters)

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to go vice-versa: declared a field with a `private` scope and getter with `public` scope (just like we usually do in Java) and got the error `Getter visibility must be the same as property visibility`. This led me to a confusion. But yes, it works the other way around.

Comment: well, what you could have also done is the following: `private var number: Int = 0` and `fun getNumber() = number`. This however is not the standard Kotlin way ;-) This way you could name the method as you like... you could even return something else then the property... (BUT!) it's definitely better to stick to the standard here :-)

Comment: Yeah, I had that idea in mind but decided to ask for a "Kotlin-way". Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for bringing up the discussion in the comments, but is it possible to declare the same property using the primary constructor, so that I can leverage `data` keyword (make `Foo` be a data class, but without setters)?

Comment: no... you can not have the `private set` within the constructor. Check also this [discuss.kotlinlang-post](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/private-setter-for-var-in-primary-constructor/3640). In that particular case you may rather do want to supply something like: `data class(private var number : Int) { fun currentCount() = number }`... and maybe there will also be support for private setter/getter in constructors in future.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to kotlin too, and it seems this is done this way:

```
class Foo {
    var number: Int = 0; private set
    fun increment() {
       ++number;
    }
}
```

As [specified in their documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters)

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin your class will be like:

```
class Foo {
    var number = 0
        get
        private set

    fun increment() {
        number++
    }
}
```

Getter is public (but anyway it is created implicitly like that, so actually we can remove it) and setter is private.